# U-Boot: "go" vs "bootz" with zImage

Tags: arm, embedded-linux, u-boot

I have a zImage for an ARM board. I consider zImage to be:

- self extracting (that is to say "executable")
- position independent

So, I guess, all I have to do is put zImage to DDR at some `0xADDRRESS` and
then just jump to the `0xADDRRESS`. But using U-Boot's `go 0xADDRRESS` doesn't get my kernel going, while `bootz 0xADDRRESS` does.

What am I missing? Why a simple jump (`go`) is not enough? What's special about `bootz`?

Comment: Linux zImage's are not necessarily position independant but might need loading to a specific address.

Comment: @Erlkoenig As for position independence on ARM. Is this one misleading/outdated https://lists.denx.de/pipermail/u-boot/2010-September/077067.html ?

Comment: Not sure, probably depends on the specific configuration/board/SoC. I think i have seen Non-PIC-ARM-zImage's :)

Comment: Linux needs atags or Dt to boot.

Comment: @artlessnoise Sure. I have `CONFIG_ARM_APPENDED_DTB` enabled (and the DTB *is* there). Shoud I still take special care about `r1` and/or `r2`?

Comment: Requirements for booting an ARM Linux kernel image are in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm/Booting   The **go** command is insufficient to meet these requirements, whereas **bootz** is implemented specifically to do so.

Comment: If you don't set the machine type to ~0, it will think it is some random machine.  It is the same with R2.  There is also MMU and caches and interrupt to be set in a known state.

Comment: 'go' command usually run the uboot standalone applications. bootz command usually used to run the kernel image, boot command also required the DT files and file system reference if needed.